# Install wordpress in backend with Existing html website alive

Tags: installation

I have created a HTML website and want to shift to wordpress. I have another theme so I will be copying my content to that theme. But I want to keep my HTML website alive till I am done with the shifting to wordpress. Is there any way I can install the wordpress database and install my theme and start my word in backend whereas the HTML still stays alive.

I am a beginner in this so please spare me for any errors.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### WordPress in [Sub Directory](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory)

Just install your WordPress site next to your HTML site in a subdirectory such as [/mysite](http://#).

While you are working on the WordPress site, it would be found in https://example.com/mysite.

Then once you are ready to switch to the WordPress site, you can just change the site url to https://example.com in the WordPress settings. This will then run your WordPress site via that same URL :)

[image]

[image]

### Safty Check

1. If you've not used local URL's in your custom links, you will have to update these manually when you change the WordPress Site URL.
2. After you have changed your URL to the root URL, it is best to scan the site and database to make sure no old URL were left unchanged. There are many good plugins and scripts that can do that. [Velvet Blues Update URLs](https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/) is one I use when transferring sites to new domains or changing from HTTPS.

Comment: This is a decent approach too - but in most cases, just updating the URL in settings isn't enough. WP stores the site URL in serialized form throughout the database. You'd need to use a database migration plugin or CLI script to make sure the URLs are truly updated throughout.

Comment: I'm pretty sure any WordPress generated links will update when you change the dir in the WordPress Site URL. However, custom links won't update, so I've added that to the answer.

Comment: Themes and plugins often store serialized data including the site URL and those values do not update automatically when you update just the Site URL and Home URL in Settings.

Comment: Yes, you are probably correct. Although I don't remember having any issues when I did this many moons ago, I do have issues when transferring domains to new domain names. I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't have to complicate yourself, simply install **WordPress** into your local machine, work on it, and when you are finished copying all the content and you are ready to launch [move your WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) from local to live. That's a clean way to go.

Comment: Oh. How could I not think about that. Thanks a lot.